# IE6 breaks cached design

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-6

I have a design which loads nicely in IE6, but as soon as I reload it 1-2 times, it all of a sudden collapses.
When I upload an updated version, it recovers from it, and breaks after a few reloads.

On a sidenote: I can't test the site on a "real" IE6, I'm using the IEtester found here:
[IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)
Maybe it's a problem with this program?

I'm sorry, I'm not allowed to post some live-code, but it is basically the Holy Grail layout found here:
[Holy Grail Layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-ems.htm)
I suspect that IE6 just can't handle the DIV-jungle and gives up sometimes.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix'd

The problem was the

```
"margin-left: -50%;
```

from

```
.holygrail .colleft
```

I changed it to a fix px-value (width of the page).

Answer (score 3):

I reloaded the Holy Grail Layout linked multiple times in IE6 and nothing happened. You can download a temporary licensed free copy of [Windows XP for Virtual PC image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) which bundles in IE6 for real testing.

Comment: This is a good idea; it also comes with the developer toolbar which makes your ie6 debugging a little easier.